# Symfony : $query->getResult() returns nothing when a table is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine, symfony

I want to show in a list all the data stored in a specific table in my database.

After doing my query, I want to get the number of results to display them or not.

```
public function listUseCaseAction(Request $request) {    
    // Load use cases from database
    $em   = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:TagUseCase');

    $query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('case')
        ->select(array('case.code', 'case.name'))
        ->orderBy('case.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    if (count($query->getResult()) > 0) {
        // display list
    } else {
        // message : "There is no use case."        
    }
}
```

The problem is that `$query->getResult()` seems to not return anything when a table is empty. Neither false nor null...

It returns a number only when there is data.

DQL :

```
'SELECT case.code, case.name FROM AppBundle\Entity\TagUseCase case ORDER BY case.name ASC'
```

**Note :** I have to get a query because I use KnpPaginator.
I tried `$repository->findAll()` and it works even a table is empty (returns an empty array) but sortable columns doesn't work anymore.
It works only with a query.

I also tried this but it doesn't work neither, it returns nothing when there is 0 result :

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select($qb->expr()->count('case.code'));
$qb->from('AppBundle:TagUseCase','case');

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

My question is : **How can I count results of a query (even if there is no result) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem !

You should never use the string "**case**" in a query, it is a SQL **reserved word** !!

Instead of :

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('case')
    ->select(array('case.code', 'case.name'))
    ->orderBy('case.name', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();
```

Write :

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select(array('c.code', 'c.name'))
    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();
```

The error `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 17: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WHEN, got 'AppBundle\Entity\TagUseCase'` is definitively no useful at all...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the query to iterate thought the list, it is better to use php count than an additional query.

Result as object, count with php:

```
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('case')
        ->orderBy('case.name', 'ASC')
        ;
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
var_dump(count($result));
```

Comment: It is exactly what there is in my first post... When I do this, I have this error : `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 17: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WHEN, got 'AppBundle\Entity\TagUseCase' `

Comment: Can you try putting the request where it belongs, in the repository? I think it it may be caused to use $repo->createQueryBuilder(public method) than $this->createQueryBuilder(protected method) instead

Comment: I created a new record manually in PhpMyAdmin and I noticed that I still had this error... But I get the data when I do `$repo->findAll();` I don't understand why the query builder throws this error...

Comment: wait... what are the other Entity than TagUseCase?

Comment: I've just tried to do my query in the repository of TagUseCase but I still have the same error...
I have a lot of different entities in my project but in the listUseCaseAction() of my controller, I only search for TagUseCase. There is another query for the connected user but I don't have this error anywhere else.

Comment: I noticed that I had this error when I do a createQuery() or createQueryBuilder() in my controller or in the repository class. But when I do `var_dump($query)` it shows a "correct" Doctrine\ORM\Query object.

Comment: good luck, I can assure you the problem is not from the syntax or the getResult. If I were you i would try to create one simple entity in a empty symfony project, check it works then compare with your current project.

Comment: It's weird because it is a very simple entity with only a code and a name. I copy-paste from another one which works well. My addUseCaseAction() works, it works when I build the form with a new TagUseCase, persist works, flush works. A new use case is stored in database. I have only a problem when I want to list my data...

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using `Query::count()` method:

```
if ($query->count()) > 0) {
    // display list
} ...
```

Comment: Returns an error : `Attempted to call an undefined method named "count" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Query". `

Comment: Oops. Looked at MongoDB ODM `Query` object instead of ORM one. Try `count(iterator_to_array($query->iterate()))`

Comment: I've just noticed I have an error just after doing the query if I use `$query` to get other variables. If I do `var_dump(iterator_to_array($query->iterate()));` just after `$query = [...] ->getQuery();` I have this error `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 17: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WHEN, got 'AppBundle\Entity\TagUseCase'`

Comment: I noticed that I had this error when I do a createQuery() or createQueryBuilder() in my controller or in the repository class. But when I do `var_dump($query)` it shows a "correct" Doctrine\ORM\Query object.